# How to a display the data from database to the databound datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms

So how to I display data from the database to datagridview??

I am using Visual Studio 2012

I am using *Window Form Application*

Here are some code that is related to make the code

```
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Co-op\Contact\Contact\ContactDataBase.sdf;Password=********");
```

This column is on my table:

`Id`, `Name`, `Adress`, `Phone`, `Email`

Comment: You need to ask a more-specific question.  What *exactly* are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of how to do it

```
using (SqlDataAdapter sa = CreateCustomAdapter(OrderIDInt))
        {
            sa.Fill(OrderTable);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = OrderTable;
        }
```

Creat your sql data adapter

```
 public static SqlDataAdapter CreateCustomAdapter(int OrderIDInt)
    {

        SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Co-op\Contact\Contact\ContactDataBase.sdf;Password=********");
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
```

Thes is a good place to create sql parameters if you need it

```
SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@CURSTAT", record.curstat);
```

Write the select command

```
        adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select Id, Name, Adress, Phone, Email from [The name of the table]", coמ);
```

If you are using sql parameters you should include thes line

```
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(param1 );
```

Then you should return the adapter

```
return adapter;
}
```